# C# find JSON value based only on Key name through multiple levels of array

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have a variety of input JSON formatted data which all contain a particular key-name `terminalSize`. This is the only piece I know. The total number of JSON trees or the exact depth of `terminalSize` inside the JSON tree will forever be an unknown and subject to change.

I'm looking for a C# solution to loop through every child of the JSON string and find `terminalSize` then fetch the value.

I've tried this with success but it will only work if `terminalSize` is in the first level of the JSON:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(jsonString);
var dict = list.SelectMany(d => d).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
var terminal = dict["terminalSize"];
```

Example 1.

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "terminalSize": 3766505.46,
    "totalTerminalSize": 3766505.46
  },
  "message": null
}
```

Example 2.

```
{
  "lastUpdated": 1588020678,
  "terminalData": {
    "terminalSize": "451679852",
    "totalTerminalSize": "2100000000"
  },
  "terminalValueSeries": {
    "8x7": 2.33,
    "8x6": 3.73,
    "8x5": 4.49,
    "8x4": 3.68,
    "8x3": 13998,
    "8x2": 274936,
    "8x1": 5.09
  }
}
```

Example 3.

```
{
  "terminalSize": "492612346.17",
  "terminalStatus": "online"
}
```

Comment: Is `terminalSize` present only once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also use linq and filter the `JProperty` collection based on `JProperty.Name`. For example

```
var result = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
                    .DescendantsAndSelf()
                    .OfType<JProperty>()
                    .Single(x=>x.Name.Equals("terminalSize"))
                    .Value;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can parse your JSON to a [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm), then use [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) with the recursive descent [JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) operator `..` to get the `terminalSize` anywhere in the JSON:

```
var terminalSize = (double?) JToken.Parse(json).SelectToken("$..terminalSize");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5ziYbP

If there might be multiple `terminalSize` keys in the JSON, for example if you had an array of terminals, you can use `SelectTokens` instead and put the terminal sizes into a `Dictionary` keyed by path:

```
var sizes = JToken.Parse(json4)
                  .SelectTokens("$..terminalSize")
                  .ToDictionary(t => t.Path, t => (double)t);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ivSM88

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle links and worked examples. Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You may parse your JSON into [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), then recursively go through all properties and sub objects to find a `terminalSize` value. There is no need to deserialize the entire JSON into specific object

```cs
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var result = GetTerminalSize(json);

double GetTerminalSize(JObject input)
{
    foreach (var property in input.Properties())
    {
        if (property.Name == "terminalSize")
            return property.Value.Value<double>();

        if (property.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            return GetTerminalSize((JObject) property.Value);

        //not sure, if the is a need to handle an array
        if (property.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            foreach (var item in (JArray) property.Value)
                return GetTerminalSize((JObject) item);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It returns a correct value for all 3 examples

Comment: Thank you, very helpful