# JArrary find value from key

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a long json string that I get from reddit which looks like: [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/luvwmy/this_baby_bat_being_washed_was_so_cute_his_little.json). Once I download and parse the string, I am looking for two parts, "fallback_url" and "thumbnail". The thing is that depending on the time that the reddit post was uploaded the format of the json string can vary so those parts can be in different spots. What I want to do is look through the objects and arrays in the JArray to find the value of "fallback_url" and "thumbnail".

I am trying to use Newtonsoft, but I am not very familiar with it, and when I try the following I get an error:

```cs
var data = JArray.Parse(json);
string path = data.Value<string>("fallback_url")?? data.Value<string>("url_overridden_by_dest");
```

> System.ArgumentException: Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "fallback_url". Int32 array index expected.

Clearly, I'm either using the function wrong or it's not the right function to use. I've tried looking online for answers, but all the examples I found directly referenced the structure of the json to find a value from a key, which I can't do.

Comment: Your root object is an **array** so can't have a `"fallback_url"` property.  In fact your JSON has two `"fallback_url"` properties, at paths `[0].data.children[0].data.secure_media.reddit_video.fallback_url` and `[0].data.children[0].data.media.reddit_video.fallback_url`; see https://dotnetfiddle.net/PWeTBP.  Which one do you want?  If you post your JSON to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ you will be able to see a formatted version, which may make things easier.

Comment: @dbc The two links will always be the same, but for speed sake it'd probably be faster to loop through to the first one than the second one. I had already used that formatter, but it doesn't matter the format of the json because the format varies between urls. All I know is that it has a falback_url in it, but I don't know where.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find JSON value based only on Key name through multiple levels of array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61468633/10263)